# Git Authentication failed. New generated token doesn't work

Tags: github, repository, token

could someone help me to fix this issue?
I'm trying to connect my local repository to GitHub, but I have got this error.
I have tried so many times to solve it without success, following the documentation or generate a new token, as well.
Thanks in advance

```bash
Username for 'https://github.com': ...@gmail.com
Password for 'https://...@gmail.com@github.com':
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls 
for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Username/horizontal-gallery.git/'
```

I would like to access again on my GitHub profile, and work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the token you are entering as a password when prompted [follows the new format](https://github.blog/2021-04-05-behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/#identifiable-prefixes):

> `ghp` for GitHub personal access tokens

And make sure you are not creating a ["fined-grained" PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-fine-grained-personal-access-token), as such token might be too limited in scope and would not work with a specific repository.
Try and create a [classic PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic).